# Is there a simple way to loop through a datagrid and replace or remove a certain character

Tags: vb.net, csv, datagrid

I have a datagrid filled from a .csv , the .csv is comma delimited.
The csv also contains commas in string fields that messes with loading it into the datagrid , the csv file also has character ' which messes with submitting to a DB later.

rather than "clean" the file before loading , is there a simple way to scan through the loaded grid and remove these characters? Or would cleaning the file first be the better way?

thanks in advance

cleaning the file before loading seems to work fine.

load code:

```
 Dim TextLine As String = ""
    Dim SplitLine() As String

    If System.IO.File.Exists(fname) = True Then
        Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(fname)

        Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
            TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()
            SplitLine = Split(TextLine.Replace("""", ""), ",")
            'SplitLine = Split(TextLine, ",")
            grdDisplay.ColumnCount = SplitLine.Count
            grdDisplay.Rows.Add(SplitLine)
        Loop
        objReader.Close()
        objReader.Dispose()
        grdDisplay.AutoResizeColumns()

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("File Does Not Exist")

    End If
```

Submit to DB code:

Dim cm As New SqlCommand
        With cm
            .Connection = cn

```
        For i As Integer = 1 To grdDisplay.RowCount - 1
            .CommandText = "insert into DefectRequestEntries values 
            ('" & grdDisplay.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value & "','  " & grdDisplay.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value & "','
              " & grdDisplay.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value & " ',' " & grdDisplay.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value & "','
              " & grdDisplay.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value & " ',' " & grdDisplay.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value & "','
              " & grdDisplay.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value & " ',' " & grdDisplay.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value & "','
              " & grdDisplay.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value & " ',' " & grdDisplay.Rows(i).Cells(9).Value & "','
              " & grdDisplay.Rows(i).Cells(10).Value & " ',' " & grdDisplay.Rows(i).Cells(11).Value & "','
              " & (grdDisplay.Rows(i).Cells(12).Value & "')")

            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    End With
```

Comment: Always user parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Comment: For csv files this is the best way. I still would check for forbitten characters see sql ionjetion  If it is possible to use xml Files, this is "simpler" because you can import them directly into tables and export them also simple

Comment: If you use Parameters to add the values that contain the ' the value will be inserted/updated as such with no exception or escaping/removing required

Comment: you could import the VisualBasic Namespace and use the [TextFieldParser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser?view=netframework-4.8) class to bring in each of the fields of the csv file.

Comment: thanks all! appreciate it!